# Could not cast value of type 'NeuroCongress.celulaTableViewCell' (0x15836c) to 'NeuroCongress.Evento

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

When I pass the object to the segue I get this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'NeuroCongress.celulaTableViewCell' (0x15836c) to 'NeuroCongress.Evento'

//------------------ newTableViewController --------------------

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! celulaTableViewCell


        cell.titLabel?.text = evento[indexPath.row].titulo
        cell.subTitLabel?.text = evento[indexPath.row].localizacao

        return cell

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // cria evento com o selecionado atual
        let evento = self.evento[indexPath.row]
        // envia evento criado acima como sender para o segue detailSegue
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailSegue", sender: evento)


    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        // envia objeto que veio via sender do didselectrow como objeto Friend para a VC FriendDetail
        detailVC.eventozinho = sender as! Evento


    }
```

//------------------ DetailViewController --------------------

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitulo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblInicio: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblFim: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblLocal: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblPais: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblContato: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblAssunto: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblWeb: UILabel!
    @IBAction func btnAbrir(sender: AnyObject) {

        openWebPage(self.eventozinho.website)

    }

    var eventozinho = Evento()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.lblTitulo.text = self.eventozinho.titulo

        self.lblInicio.text = String(self.eventozinho.dtinicio!)
        self.lblFim.text = String(self.eventozinho.dttermino!)

        self.lblLocal.text = self.eventozinho.localizacao
        self.lblPais.text = self.eventozinho.pais

        self.lblWeb.text = self.eventozinho.website

        self.lblAssunto.text = self.eventozinho.assunto
        self.lblContato.text = self.eventozinho.contato
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have created the segue in your storyboard by dragging from the table view cell prototype to the DetailViewController.  The segue is therefore triggered automatically when you tap the cell - in this case, the `sender` argument is the cell which was tapped.  Hence the error: your prepareForSegue assumes that the sender argument is the `Event`, but it is in fact the cell.  If you set up the segue in this way, there is no need to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to trigger the segue.  In fact, the prepareForSegue runs *before* the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is called.  You can amend the `prepareForSegue` to use `indexPathForCell` (passing the `sender` - you might need to cast it correctly) to determine the correct indexPath (and hence which Event to pass to the destination view controller).

Alternatively, in your storyboard remove the segue and re-create it by dragging from the view controller itself (using the icon at the top of the scene) to the DetailViewController.  In this case, your current code should work - the`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code will run and trigger the segue, passing the Event as the sender.

Comment: Thank you, you are the guy.